# Vertx 3.7.0+ Using the RedisAPI - Counterpart of mgetMany

Tags: redis, vert.x

In vertx prior to 3.7, there was a redis client method [mgetmany](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/redis/RedisClient.html#mgetMany-java.util.List-io.vertx.core.Handler-):

```
RedisClient mgetMany(List<String> keys,
                     Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler)
Get the values of all the given keys
```

In the native redis methods what is the counterpart of this?

How could we replace this method using the new [RestAPI](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its equivalent redis command is `MGET`.
refer [redis doc here](https://redis.io/commands/mget)

You can use any redis client lib to call redis. (For example Jedis, Redision, Lettuce), which will provide you easy to use APIs